# Using a Local Variable in a Recursive Function

Tags: recursion, processing, fractals

I have a bit of Processing 3 code to draw an animated fractal. The issue is that the program only draws a single dot. I had the program working previously. The only thing I changed was support for a variable number of 'sides'.

```
float angle, scale;
int sides;

void setup(){
  size(600, 600);
  background(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  stroke(255);
  sides = 3;
}

void draw(){
  background(0, 64);
  angle = cos(frameCount*0.025);
  scale = sin(frameCount*0.01);
  fractal(width/2, height/2, 100, 7);
}

void fractal(float x, float y, float s, int d){
  ellipse(x, y, 2, 2);
  if(d > 0){
    float dir = PI/2;
    for(int i = 0; i > sides; i++){
      fractal(x + s/sqrt(3) * cos(dir + angle), y + s/sqrt(3) * sin(dir + angle), s * scale, d - 1);
      dir += TWO_PI/sides;
    }
  }
}
```

I believe the issue lies in the recursive function overwriting the local variable 'dir' each iteration, however, I do not know that for sure. I have a working version of the program that uses a fixed number of sides if you would like to see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The issue is a simple typo. It has to be `i < sides` instead of `i > sides`. The for loop is never entered. Anyway cool animation.

Comment: Oh, wow. That's embarrassing. At least it was an easy fix! Thanks a bunch!